# XSLT count() including reference node comparison

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My XML Code (containing pubs and people):

```
<document>
    <pubs>
        <pub id="pub1">
            <open>true</open>
        </pub>
        <pub id="pub2">
            <open>false</open>
        </pub>
    </pubs>
    <people>
        <person>
            <name>John</name>
            <pubId>pub1</pubId>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Paul</name>
            <pubId>pub2</pubId>
        </person>
    </people>
</document>
```

uses a reference from `<person>` to `<pub>` (`person/pubId` references `pub[@id]`). Pubs themselves have a boolean `<open>` (stating whether the pub is opened or closed).

Using XSLT, I want to be able to `count()` the number of people that can go to the pub. In order to go to a pub, the pub must have an `<open>` value of `true`.

Two possible solutions that I can't quite code up:

1. Iterate through the people and keep track of the number:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="person">
       <xsl:variable name="pId" select="pubId" />

       <xsl:if test="root()/document/pubs/pub[@pubId=$pId]/open = 'true'" >
           <!-- any way to keep track of this number? -->
       </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```
2. Use the count() function directly:

   ```
   <count>
       <xsl:value-of select="count(//person[root()/document/pubs/pub[@id = pubId]/open = 'true'])" />
   </count>
   ```

The second option seems more concise and correct, but I can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this XPath 1.0 one-liner**:

```
count(/*/people/person[pubId = /*/pubs/pub[open = 'true']/@id])
```

This returns the count of `person` elements in this document that have at least one `pubId` child such that there is a `pub` element whose `id` attribute's string value equals that `pubId` and whose `open` child's string value is the string `"true"`.

**Here is an XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
      "count(/*/people/person[pubId = /*/pubs/pub[open = 'true']/@id])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<document>
    <pubs>
        <pub id="pub1">
            <open>true</open>
        </pub>
        <pub id="pub2">
            <open>false</open>
        </pub>
    </pubs>
    <people>
        <person>
            <name>John</name>
            <pubId>pub1</pubId>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Paul</name>
            <pubId>pub2</pubId>
        </person>
    </people>
</document>
```

**the Xpath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
1
```

Comment: Simplest solution for me. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a key to look up the pubs

```
<xsl:key name="pubs" match="pub" use="@id" />
```

This would allow you to simplify your count to the following

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//person[key('pubs', pubId)[open='true']])"/>
```

So, for the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="pubs" match="pub" use="@id" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <count>
         <xsl:value-of select="count(//person[key('pubs', pubId)[open='true']])"/>
      </count>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following is output

```
<count>1</count>
```

Note that in XSLT variables are immutable, and cannot be changed once set. So, your first approach about trying to set a variable and increment would not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the second approach is the correct one: it's essentially doing a join. As Tim C points out, keys are often useful for doing joins in XSLT.

The reason your attempt

```
count(//person[root()/document/pubs/pub[@id = pubId]/open = 'true'])
```

doesn't work is that the context for 'pubId' is wrong. You can solve this in XPath 2.0 using a range variable:

```
count(for $p in //person return (if (/document/pubs/pub[@id = $p/pubId]/open = 'true') then $p else ()))
```

but using keys is simpler and faster.